# Windows Application With Multiple Users

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Windows application with SQL and Crystal Reports. I just want to prepare it for multiple users, so that it can be operated from more than one local computer. The data of the transaction should be stored at one server and it could be read or written by more than one local computer.

I don’t have any idea of how to do it?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundemental question of "how to build an n-Tier application" and is a bit broad for a "quick answer" here.

I will offer these two links as a good starting point for you.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973279.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978384.aspx

There are, of course, other resources and opinions. I would encourage you to start here and then as you encounter more specific questions please ask those.

Cheers,

CEC

**EDIT: C# specific link** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx

Comment: @Cos Callis, Yes it is itself good tutorials but it's of VB I shall  prefer to c#

Comment: @Mahesh, I was offering those as good information about application architecture. I have added a C# specific link. The concepts and practices are the same regardless of the language.

Comment: .... And if i am not wrong than it is for wpf not for winform application. I am interested in winform application.

Comment: The broad strokes still apply. Just translate it in your head. Think of it as learning the principal of the matter. For practical application you can post more detailed questions.

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh, see I am just interested in local computer system which are connected through LAN. I don't wont to JOIN Server Online.

Comment: ... If you have any suggestion than please suggest.

Comment: @Cos Callis, I think the suggested link is good and i will try it later thanks for your valuable suggestion.